# Pandas merge columns if 'NaN' value is present in one line code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset `df` looks like this:

```
time         high      low     offset
2017-01-01   1.012     0.921    NaN
2017-01-02   1.019     0.934    NaN 
2017-01-03   1.213     NaN      0.982
2017-01-04   1.112     0.965    NaN
```

here, either `low` value is `NaN` or `offset` value is `NaN` but not both

I want to create a new column called `low_offset_merge`

so that `low_offset_merge` will contain the merged values of `low` and `offset` and it will all have a `number` value and no `NaN`, like below:

```
time         high      low     offset  low_offset_merge
2017-01-01   1.012     0.921    NaN       0.921
2017-01-02   1.019     0.934    NaN       0.934
2017-01-03   1.213     NaN      0.982     0.982
2017-01-04   1.112     0.965    NaN       0.965
```

What did I do?

```
- First, check if `low` has `NaN` values and set the value     
df.loc[df['low'] != 'NaN', 'low_offset_merge'] = df['offset']

- Second, fill in the `NaN` column
df['low_offset_merge'] = df['low_offset_merge'].fillna(value=df['offset'])
```

I am looking for a one-line solution, can you please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close with your last attempt using `fillna`. You don't need to check for `NaN` values first, you can just directly fill the missing values with values from another column:

```
df['low_offset_merge'] = df['low'].fillna(df['offset'])
```

Comment: so it first fills in the value from `df['low']` and then if there are any `NaN` values, then it uses values from `df['offset']`?

Comment: Yeah basically. It will take the values in `df['low']`, looking for any cells where there are `NaN`, and fill those spaces with values from `offset`. The result is then stored in the new column. So neither of the original columns are actually changed